# How to modify TFS build automation workflow without .Net Compiler, need to use Team Developer's Language compiler

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am trying build automation for a project developed using legacy language called Team Developer 6. where each file needs to be compiled as an exe. also need to do some filter activity before building exes. there are 300 exes.

this process I could do in simple .Net utility which does the filtering and invokes Team Developer compiler for required files.

Is it possible to put this in to TFS build work flow? what is the best approach for this?

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: my tfs version is 2010 now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an MSBuild project that invokes the necessary commands for the tooling you require and check it in. In the TFS build definition, make use of the default template (at first) and set the MSBuild project file you created as the 'project to build'.

This way you can test your build process locally with MSBuild on the command line, and determine which command line switches you might need. You can set command line switches into the build definition, or if you need some further control you can modify the default template to inject the command line switches directly into the MSBuild activity.

I recommend this way, as then you won't have to create any customized workflow, and can avoid having to go down the road of using custom workflow activities in TFS (which is absolutely supported, but in my opinion a bit difficult to diagnose/debug/maintain/upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

You would ideally want to [use an InvokeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_InvokeProcess) activity to call an executable which does the filtering and invoking. An alternative but more complex approach would be to create a custom activity, but that requires installation of binaries on the build servers.